# How to make the control on same page till text boxes got correct no. of characters?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have created two text boxes and wrote the JSfunction to give alert msg that both the boxes together should be of 50 characters. Function called in onclick() event in Submit button. Also in controller Store() function, save the content of these two text boxes and validated with "required", then redirected to another page.
Problem is, if I give less than 50 characters it shows alert msg, but store the data even less than 50 characters given and redirected to specified page. If i give less than 50 characters, after showing the alert msg, it has to be in the same page until i give together 50 characters. It should ave the textboxes content only if more than 50 characters. Can anyone help me?

**In create.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('training.applicants.aim.create.process', $request->training_request_id)}}">
<div class="form-group" id="goal_group" >
    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold" for="ziele[1]">Ziele 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="ziele[1]" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('ziele.1') is-invalid @enderror" id="ziele.1" >
    @error('ziele.1') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->get('ziele.1')[0] }}</div> @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold" for="ziele[2]">Ziele 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="ziele[2]" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('ziele.2') is-invalid @enderror" id="ziele.2" >
    @error('ziele.2') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->get('ziele.2')[0] }}</div> @enderror
</div>
<div id="additional_goals"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="form-group row container-fluid" >
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-2 float-right">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" style="position: absolute; right:0" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="submit_btn" onclick="goal_validation()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Js function:**

```
function goal_validation()
{
    var l1=document.getElementById('ziele.1').value;
    var l2=document.getElementById('ziele.2').value;
    var Total=50-(l1.length +l2.length);

    if(Total<50 && Total>0)
    {
        alert("U have to give minimum "+Total+" characters");
    }
}
```

**In controller store function:**

```
public function storeGoals(TrainingRequest $antrag, Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        //'ziele.*' => 'required|string',
        'ziele.1' => 'required|string',
        'ziele.2' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $antrag->goals = isset($request->ziele) ? $request->ziele : NULL;
    $antrag->save();

    return redirect()
         ->route('Training.participation.mein', $request)
         ->with('Message', $Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `strlen()` function to find character length.

```
      $request->validate([
            //'ziele.*' => 'required|string',
            'ziele.1' => 'required|string',
            'ziele.2' => 'required|string',

        ]);
       
             length1= strlen($request->ziele.1);
             length2= strlen($request->ziele.2);

           if((length1+length2) >= 50){  

             $antrag->goals = isset($request->ziele) ? $request->ziele : NULL;
             $antrag->save();
             return redirect()
                    ->route('Training.participation.mein', $request)
                    ->with('Message', $Message);

             }
            else{
            return redirect()->back();
             }
```